# What test should I use for correlation of categorical and discrete variable in R?

Tags: r, correlation, chi-squared-test

Here is a a portion of my data:

`(list(GroupName = c("BBC",  "BBC", "FOT", "FOT", "TAR", "TAR"), annual_grpsize = c(10L, 14L,  3L, 10L, 6L, 2L), Date = c("01/01/2015", "01/01/2015", "01/01/2015",  "01/01/2015", "02/01/2015", "03/01/2015")), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")`

I want to look at whether there is a significant correlation between the groups and the group sizes.
The group size is discrete, with minimum value of 2 and a maximum value of 15. Would it be sensible for me to take group size as a 'categorical' variable, and do a Chi-Squared test? Or is there an alternative test to assess correlation between a discrete (group size) and categorical (Group) variable?

I've given below all the groups and the number of observations in each group.
[image: Number of groups & observations in each group]

Comment: I would advise you use an ANOVA test, which can be used to test the difference in a continuous dependent variable between three or more groups (in your case these groups would be your GroupName variable). Using a chi-sq test (and treating your group size as categorical) may be more difficult to interpret due to the number of possible group sizes (13?)

Comment: How many observations do you have per group? Do you just have two observations for BBC, two observations for FOX, and two observations for TAR?

Comment: I've edited the question to show #of observations for each group, it ranges from 1 to 310 across 27 groups. Also apologies for the type, FOX is meant to be FOT.

Comment: @jros and It doesn't matter that the group size is a discrete variable, not continuous?

Comment: It will depend on what assumptions you have about the group size. More specific than a discrete variable, you have a *count* variable. You might want to make an assumption about having a Poisson or negative binomial distribution of group sizes within each category. (Either of those could be terrible assumptions, but either could be reasonable, too.) Nothing keeps you from doing something like ANOVA for distribution families other than the normal distribution. // Since there are so many factors and options, perhaps it would be best to describe the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @BurtonGuster as Dave suggested, describing your problem could help with that advice. Treating your group size as continuous could be appropriate

Comment: Sure - eventually I will be making a model with various factors that may affect nest site placement, and I suspected that the group or the size of the group (group = family of individuals making the nest) may be independent variables influencing this response variable. So I wanted to first determine whether the group size was significantly different across groups.